# Show a warning during import, when MySQL dump contains `use`

Tags: mysql, bash

Let's suppose I have large MySql dump which I want to import to a specific database.

I could use

`mysql -D bar --one-database < foo.mysql`

`foo.mysql` has a `use foo;` somewhere.

This command is already doing most of what I want: Ignoring data which would be important to another database than `bar`.

I could use a `grep -e "^use " foo.mysql` to check if the database dump contains a use statement.

But can I do this also during the import, so I do not have to read the dump twice?

Comment: `use` is a valid mysql command. Unless the database referenced in `use` does not exists, no warning is generated.

Comment: @hakre `mysqldump --all-databases` for example. Or just a dump from somebody else where I do not know how they created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading while importing example:

```
< dump.sql tee >(sed -n '/^USE `[^`]*`;$/ p' 1>&2) | mysql ...
```

The example will import the file `dump.sql` into mysql while printing the use-statements as they come by:

```
...
USE `blue-racoon`;
USE `funny-basil`;
USE `purple-fish`;
...
```

Explanation: If you have a full dump with all databases of the mysql server (`--all-databases` long option) and you would like to review all SQL `USE`-statements *while* the file pipes into mysql, you could make use of *`tee`* to duplicate the content on the fly and *`sed`* to only print from those duplicated lines if a line is a `USE`-statement.

Then the filtered output is redirected to *STDERR* for review while the unfiltered output can be imported as normal by *mysql*.

I hope this helps.